# Ruby styles for image doesn't resize pictures properly

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

could someone explain me what should I do to fix this? I put this on **post.rb**

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }
 validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
```

then in my **index.html.erb** i got this

```
      <div class="row">
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>   
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm ">
        <img class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top img-fluid "   ><%= image_tag post.image.url(:medium) %></img>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text"><h3><%= post.title %> </h3> <%= post.body %></p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
                    <%= link_to "View", post_path(post), :class =>'btn btn-md btn-outline-secondary' %>
                    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post), :class =>'btn btn-md btn-outline-secondary' %>
              </div>
<small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<% end %>

</div>
```

When I upload diffrent images then it doesn't resize it properly: look at this: https://iv.pl/image/resize-ruby.Gt21xMz
I use paperclip and Magick to upload images.

Answer (score 0):

I checked through the docs for Paperclip, and it appears that `300x300>` and `100x100>` are directives passed to ImageMagick.

https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry says that `300x300>` will shrink the image so that it fits within 300x300.  That means if you have a picture that's 500x300, it'll shrink down to 300x180.

`{ medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }` looks like the line of code to modify, to change your resizing.

The picture that renders correctly is probably close to square in its original form.  The picture that does not is probably a wide rectangle.

Comment: So am I supposed to put higer resolution e.g. has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "400x225>"} I think that works.

Comment: What do you want?

If you want square images, `300x300#` will make them square (but distorted).

If you want your layout cards to be aligned, then your resizing is doing just fine.  You need to set your view code (CSS or HTML) so that the image containers are `min-height: 300px`.